# how to get php data at javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is a php file below named getques.php at server. In this php file, the variables subnm1, chpno1 and qnumber1 are posted from a html-javascript file from client side. With these, a database at server is accessed and the output of SQL query is stored in a variable $px.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <?php
$x = $_POST["subnm1"];
$y = $_POST["chpno1"];
$z = $_POST["qnumber1"];


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","compete7_bhunia","pr393ss","compete7_iitmock");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();   }


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT question, optiona, optionb, optionc, optiond,   
 coroption FROM $x WHERE qnumber = $z AND chapno = $y");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $px = $row['question'];



 }


mysqli_close($con);
 ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

This $px is showing its desired data that has been retrieved from database. Now, I want that this variable $px should be passed to the same html-javascript file. How to get it at javascript. The relevant part is as below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var abc = "<?=echo $px ?>";

  alert(abc);

  </script>
```

This is not showing the value of $px. Pl. help.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using short open tags.May be in your php short open tags is not enabled. So try like this..

```
var abc = "<?php echo $px ?>";
```

short_open_tag directive) with PHP 5.3 or below (but since PHP 5.4.0,

Actually, in the php.ini-production file provided with PHP 5.3.0, they are disabled by default:

```
$ grep 'short_open' php.ini-production
; short_open_tag
short_open_tag = Off
```

So, using them in an application you want to distribute might not be a good idea: your application will not work if they are not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
<?php echo $px ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you have a syntax error, your output line should read like

```
var abc = "<?php echo $px ?>";
```

However, this is **not safe** (and don't use short open tags `<?=`, as they may be disabled in PHP < 5.4): consider that `$px` contains a double quote, then your syntax will be malformed; it is even possible to inject JavaScript code this way. Don't do this!

A safer method is to use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
var abc = <?php echo json_encode($px) ?>;
```

(Note that you don't need to surround this with quotes.)

On a side note, you are vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Please use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent this.